# Mejorar la consulta de Data Explorer "Percent Answered (in SE sites or '% Answered' in Area51 statistics)"

Tags: discusión, data-explorer

Usando como [base una consulta](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/530265/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics) del usuario [Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) me encuentro con un problema que quiero resolver.

A la consulta original, le agregué las columnas `Año` y `Mes`, pero no puedo presentar el porcentaje de preguntas contestadas en formato con dos decimales como la pregunta original.

Adicionalmente, el gráfico resultante no tiene sentido por lo que resulta inútil.

Esta es la consulta:

```sql
WITH Answers AS (
  SELECT ParentId AS Id, MAX(Score) AS Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY ParentId
)
, Counts AS (
  SELECT
    -- Count for questions joined with answers
    datepart(YEAR, Q.CreationDate) Year,
    datepart(MONTH, Q.CreationDate) Mes,
    COUNT(*) AS Preguntas,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS AcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL AND A.Score > 0 AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0))
      AS PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS Closed
  FROM Posts Q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers A
    ON Q.Id = A.Id
  WHERE Q.PostTypeId = 1
  group by datepart(year, Q.CreationDate), datepart(month, Q.CreationDate)
)

SELECT 
  Year, Mes, Preguntas, AcceptedNotClosed, PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed, Closed,
  (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) AS Contestadas,

  CAST((AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) AS FLOAT) / 
     CAST(PREGUNTAS AS FLOAT) * 100
     AS Porcentaje

FROM Counts
ORDER BY Year, Mes
```

Y este es el enlace, por si quieren ver el gráfico:

- [Percent Answered (in SE sites or '% Answered' in Area51 statistics)](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/646457/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no puedo presentar el porcentaje de preguntas contestadas en formato con dos decimales como la pregunta original

Para llevar a 2 decimales, se puede convertir usando:

```sql
 cast(columna as decimal(18,2))
```

En tu consulta, quedaría:

```sql
CAST(
   (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) / 
   CAST(Preguntas as FLOAT) * 100
   as decimal(18,2)
) as Porcentaje
```

---

> el gráfico resultante no tiene sentido

Eso es porque SEDE sólo toma la primera columna como eje de abscisas para graficar, por lo que es necesario unir `Año` y `Mes` en la misma columna.

Teniendo una fecha, con esta fórmula se obtiene el primer día del mes de cada fecha

```sql
dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, fecha), 0)
```

En tu consulta:

```sql
SELECT
       dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, Q.CreationDate), 0) Fecha,
       -- El resto de las columnas
```

Y usamos lo mismo en el `group by`.

---

#### Resultado:

```sql
WITH Answers AS (
  -- unique answers with best score per question
  SELECT ParentId AS Id, MAX(Score) AS Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY ParentId
)
, Counts AS (
  SELECT
    -- Count for questions joined with answers
    dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, Q.CreationDate), 0) Fecha,
    COUNT(*) AS Preguntas,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS AcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL AND A.Score > 0 AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0))
      AS PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS Closed
  FROM Posts Q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers A
    ON Q.Id = A.Id
  WHERE Q.PostTypeId = 1
  group by dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, Q.CreationDate), 0)
)

SELECT 
  Fecha, 

  Preguntas, 
  AcceptedNotClosed "Aceptadas que no fueron cerradas", 
  PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed "No aceptadas pero con puntaje positivo",
  Closed "Cerradas",
  (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) AS "Total Contestadas",

  CAST(
     (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) / 
     CAST(Preguntas AS FLOAT) * 100
     as decimal(18,2)
   ) as Porcentaje

FROM Counts
ORDER BY Fecha
```

**Consulta en SEDE:** http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/646487/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics

No obstante, la variación en el porcentaje de respondidas (entre 0 y 1) es despreciable frente al resto de las columnas, por lo que te recomiendo sólo graficar el porcentaje.

**Gráfico en SEDE:** http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/646465/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics#graph

> Nota: quizás sea engañoso, pero este gráfico **no muestra la evolución**, sólo muestra, según el estado actual, qué porcentaje de preguntas no están respondidas, según su fecha de creación, segmentadas por mes.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene la línea de porcentaje en ese gráfico? El eje Y es del orden de miles y el porcentaje nunca pasará de centenares.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si te referís al primer gráfico, no tiene sentido mostrar el porcentaje, pero era una respuesta directa a la pregunta. Por ese motivo es que había agregado un segundo gráfico mostrando sólo el porcentaje para cada mes.